# button placement below 767px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have taken over a part time front-end developer job, and I can see there is **a lot** of cleaning up to do. The page are not using bootstrap, but a homemade grid inspired from the bootstrap grid. That is the first challenge.

I am trying to figure out why the button "**Apply for account**" is jumping under the picture, when the screen is under `767px`, and a text is jumping under aswell: [Link to website](https://mimsi.dk/en-dk).

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-cta-br" style="font-size:0.975em;">
   <div id="proddesc2">
     <div id="smhead" style="font-size:0.975em; color:#ffffff;">
       <p><strong><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> If you have a workshop or a spare parts shop, you can buy BMW parts at KOED with many benefits. Read more about our business account and all the benefits.</strong></p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<a href="/da-dk/page/koed-b2b/">
   <button type="button" class="btncta4">Apply for a business account</button>
</a>
```

The `<br`> tags of course has to be removed. When I remove "Static" from the class: `btn-cta-br`, the button is rendering better, but I cannot make it fit like I want(Se screenshot). Does anybody have an idea how I could make the button and text fit?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .btn-cta-br {
      position:static;
      margin-top:15px;
      margin-left:5px;
      right:4%;
      width:80%;
      color:black;
      font-size:115%;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you remove all the <br> and also the text that is not being displayed anyway. It will align perfectly fine inside the picture. If you cant remove the text, you can try aligning it with position: relative

Comment: Thanks for the comments. To remove the <br> will not solve the problem. The text will not show on desktop, and to set it as relative is not making the button placement correct.

Comment: What do you mean with the text won't show on desktop? Using <br> to position text is a terrible way of doing so.

Comment: We agree on that, I did not make that. If you remove the <br> tags in the inspector window it is not helping placing the button. The text still needs to be there.

Comment: Thats why i said, if you are unable to remove the text, use `position: relative;` to position the button to where you want it.

Comment: Also setting the text to display:none for mobile view only will almost clear the wierd space aswell. Or is that text meant to be displayed on mobile view aswell?

Comment: So I place the button with relative on desktop and media query. I remove the <br> tags, and set the button to a display: none?

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Setting the text (which is invisible for me anyway) to display:none; fixes most of the problem. Or even better, hiding the div with the ID: smhead. But if that is your answer, depends on what you want to do with the text.

Comment: Where is the picture? Also, the link isn't working.